# How to navigate back to my app instead of going down the backstack?

Tags: java, android

Let's say the user presses a button which causes another activity to get launched. Now the user is in another activity. What flag do I have to add to the intent, so that the user returns to my app when pressing the back button instead of navigating down the back stack of the started activity?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, "activities on the backstack are never rearranged."

[Android documentation Tasks and BackStack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add anything to the intent. When you navigate out of you app and start another activity to complete a task, the new activity becomes kind of like an extension of your app. Pressing the back button takes you back to your app. [Read This](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#between-apps)

Comment: Check that it is the back button and not the Up button you are pressing. because the back button takes you back, while the up button keeps you within the app.